# Protein mix - How long can it sit?

Tags: protein

How long will a protein mix last before it isn't any good? Should I always mix it as soon as I want to drink it or can I pre mix a few bottles then store them in the fridge? I'm talking about using the tubs of powder, not actually buying the pre-mixed bottles like the 6 packs of Muscle Milk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know the actual life of a mixed protein shake, but I wouldn't drink anything over 24 hours old.  If you want convenience what I would do is pre-fill the bottles with the powder and fill with water or milk when needed.  You will need to re-shake it anyway.

Comment: I should have added in my question I dont expect anything to last more than 12-16 hours. I dont want to mix for the week but maybe mix the night before so I can have one in the morning and one at lunch.

Comment: What I will do when I go to the gym in the morning is mix my shake first around 6am then sip on it throughout the day.

Answer (score 1):

When refrigerated, I would expect it to last at least 48 hours. If not refrigerated, I would suspect that you wouldn't want to leave it sit at room temperature for more than a few hours.

For lunch, you could try freezing it overnight and taking it out in the morning, then it should stay mostly cold until lunch time. Although, @Salsero69 's suggestion of measuring the powder then mixing when needed is probably the best solution.