# Preservatives in protein-shake powder?

Tags: nutrition-information, protein-shakes

I purchased protein shake powder a few months ago. I've been storing it at room temperature in my kitchen, temporarily also in the fridge. Produced in 08/2010, expriation date 02/2012.

What kind of preservatives does this powder contain, and are they any way problematic?

Come on, there must be powerful preservatives inside this stuff,  because it has high nutritional value, has very low grain size, is very sweet and, thus, should be a really good breeding ground for microorganisms. But until now, nothing seems to have changed inside the plastic containers. The coconut taste sometime is a bit murky, but this can be by design or maybe the concentration was too high.

This question: [Protein mix - How long can it sit?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/3074/protein-mix-how-long-can-it-sit) refers to the max duration a shake can be stored after water has been added and the shake is ready to drink (2 hours). I'm referring to the powder form here.

Edit - Ingredients: Calcium caseinate, milk protein concentrate, whey protein concentrate, protein enriched whey powder, Egg albumin, flavouring, glucose syrup, banana powder, Mg carbonate, Vegetable oil, sweeteners: Aspartame and acesulfame-k, vitamin c; niacin, Beta carotin, pantothenic acid, Vitamin B6, vitamin B1, riboflavine

Comment: ... Aspartame is a preservative..

Comment: @user26818 - No. Aspartame is a sweetener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't look like any preservatives in there to me. Just because it's sweet doesn't mean it'll breed microorganisms. Think about powdered sugar. It's super-fine, and lasts forever. I think the dryness of the protein powder is what keeps it lasting a long time.

Comment: he is right, it's the dryness.. make a protein shake and leave it there.. should go bad immediately